# Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, animation

i was wondering if anybody knows (and if there is such a thing) a javascript plugin that can do to following:
on the website http://www.worldofmerix.com/ click on any of the menu buttons on top for eg. "about us"; then you see a line appear in the middle and expand so that you can see the entire div...
I need a similar animation effect, flash is out of the question, so i have to use javascript...
i have some ideas on making it with some "smooth div fade in/out" js plugins, but i was wondering if there is a plugin SPECIFIC to the thing i need?
thanks very much in advance for the anwsers!

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It has all the functionality you need.

Comment: @Cipi: I think you need to be a bit more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you didn't state any jQuery "dont-wanting" I'd recommend you to check out [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). It is a set of JavaScript libraries that help you manage your HTML and CSS with some light code.

You can see [HERE](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php), [HERE](http://cdn.net.tutsplus.com/041_TopPanelWithJquery/demo/index.html#) and [HERE](http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html) how it can animate divs and other elements (I see that it is what you need).

You can check out the official web site and there you can find all kinds of examples and documentation that you will ever need. I recommend you to see [THIS](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (click RUN).